# Why commit changes if I cannot see the old versions of my files?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and I see that people recommend to commit your files a lot "to keep track of your changes", but I don't understand the purpose. Where can I see my old files (the ones from an earlier commit)?

I read that it is possible to retrieve them somehow but it didn't seem simple to me. So why should I commit? Is it not easier to just make a normal copy of my files?

It would be really nice if someone could explain the advantage to me.

Comment: Think of a commit as a snapshot of your files. You can go back to older "snapshots" by checking out that commit. Useful if you realize that changes you made doesn't work and want to restore back to a working state. But more importantly, allows you to make changes independently of others while still keeping track of everyone's changes. Which you can merge everyone's changes to a single "snapshot"

Comment: You should read something like this: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch01.html

Comment: View file `path/to/file` 3 commits ago with `git show HEAD~3:path/to/file`.  In general, `git show $ref:$path`.  There are a *lot* of ways to specify the content that you wish to view.

Comment: Have you tried GitHub? It's less obscure than the git CLI for beginners

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.23.0) to see your previous commits, it should look something like this:

```
commit c69112c0614624dce5576617f05f68965995dc34 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Maurits van Riezen (mousetail) <mousetail@mousetail.nl>
Date:   Fri Jul 30 09:32:35 2021 +0200

    add historic maximum bot

commit 7e1ef7bec12cf2156761d1d22ff82c2a544dfcc8
Author: Maurits van Riezen (mousetail) <mousetail@mousetail.nl>
Date:   Wed Jul 28 18:59:41 2021 +0200

    initial commit
```

Then you can go back to any version using [git switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch/2.23.0):

```
git switch --detach 7e1ef7bec12cf2156761d1d22ff82c2a544dfcc8
```

You can also look up branches and tags for more high level ways of organizing your project's history.

Answer (score 1):

Version control can definitely be done by making copies of files and storing them with different names/locations.
Over time, people found this way to be rather convoluted, as over years of code development it becomes a sea of different filenames.

Having the same filenames also allows code to be compiled/scripted easily, as filenames don't have to change.

Git allows one to save the same file over time with timestamps, and keeps track of differences in the file. You can checkout an older commit to go back in time in your git repo, among other methods to get older files back.

Comment: `s/years/hours/`

Comment: s/hours/minutes/

Comment: `s/minutes of code development/time`

Comment: What do these notations mean? s/years/hours etc? Sorry I'm from a more automation background.